# Laravel - Query to get items that appear more than once

Tags: laravel

I have this query in Laravel

```
$billings = DB::table('billing as b')
    ->select(
       'b.sender', 
       'b.message',
       'b.amount',
       DB::raw('DATE(b.created_at) as billing_date'),
       'b.billing_type', 
       'b.service_name',
       'b.package_name'
  )                                                         
 ->orderByRaw('b.created_at DESC')
 ->get();
```

I want the query to be where **sender** appear more than once.

How do I achieve this please?

Comment: have your tried anything?

Comment: from my check on the query statement above, it queries all the records with senders more than once.

Comment: Yes. But I want it that where sender appears more than once

Comment: You can look this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/finding-duplicate-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use groupby and having together:

```
$billings = DB::table('billing as b')
    ->select(
       'b.sender', 
       'b.message',
       'b.amount',
       DB::raw('DATE(b.created_at) as billing_date'),
       'b.billing_type', 
       'b.service_name',
       'b.package_name'
  )                                                         
 ->orderByRaw('b.created_at DESC')
 ->groupBy('sender')  //added
 ->having('sender', '>', 1) //added
 ->get();
```